# Scan String with Ruby Regular Expression

Tags: ruby, regex, pattern-matching, scanf

I am attempting to scan the following string with the following regular expression:

```
 text = %q{akdce ALASKA DISTRICT COURT CM/ECFalmdce 
           ALABAMA MIDDLE DISTRICT COURTalndce
          }

 p courts = text.scan(/(ECF\w+)|(COURT\w+)/)
```

Ideally, what I want to do is scan the text and pull the text 'ECFalmdce' and 'COURTalndce'
With the regex I am using, I am trying to say I want a string that starts with either COURT or ECF followed by a random string of characters.

The array being returned is:

```
 [["ECFalmdce", nil], [nil, "COURTalndce"]]
```

What is the deal with the nil's, does anyone have a more efficient way of writing the regex, and does anyone have a link to further documentation on match groups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex captures differently for `ECF` and `COURT`. You can create non-capture groups with `?:`

```
text.scan(/(?:ECF|COURT)\w+/)
# => ["ECFalmdce", "COURTalndce"]
```

**Edit**

About non-capture groups: You can use them to create patterns using parenthesis without capturing the pattern.

They're patterns such as `(?:pattern)`

You can find more information on regular expressions at http://www.regular-expressions.info/refadv.html

Comment: what are non-capture groups?

Comment: Don't capture the whole pattern. Using `/(?:ECF|COURT)\w+/` instead will avoid creating the sub-arrays.